Monitoring regions when app is in background or just terminated
Does having in plist [UIBackgroundModes: Location Updates] and set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates to true is helping at all if I use only monitoring regions (CLMonitor or CLLocationManager) with no running startUpdatingLocation? I am looking for this for hours and can't find clear answer. In some places I found that it may help if there are problems in background modes and in other places I found that it's not relevant. Official apple docs are also not very clear about this and they are very chaotic
Also, since ios17 there is CLBackgroundActivitySession and I wonder if I should look into this direction
In our app we notice some problems around this case so I am looking for solutions. We don't use Location Updates and allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates is set to false but we use only Monitoring Regions. For now we don't force users to set Always right after when user set permissions to When-in-use (when popup displayed first time there is no Always option and since ios13.4 https://medium.com/swlh/location-permission-in-ios-13-f9e10917c05e we can make a double popup). Ofc we ask for Always since beginning but IOS doesn't display this option. It should display this later automatically
Edit. We don't use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges and pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically is set to false and DesiredAccuracy is set to "1", DistanceFilter is default (none)

Please check this article, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78589879/monitoring-regions-when-app-is-in-background-or-just-terminated they are not using location update code

This apple article https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/monitoring_the_user_s_proximity_to_geographic_regions also not using location updates

A tip: don't forget to add the required background modes keys: Location updates and Background fetch  in your info,plist file.

@AlexandarMay-MSFT this topic is exactly about this if there is any advantage to add this when using only region monitoring :D During my personal tests I don't see any advances. I mean monitoring is working fine without adding anything to info.plist

Yes, that's just a tip. Consider background updates only when your app needs to receive those updates in real time, perhaps to: Take immediate action when someone enters or exits a particular geographic region. See Handling location updates in the background.

The Apple documentation describes the cases where a terminated app will be relaunched -

The system can terminate apps at any time to free up memory or other system resources. The system relaunches a terminated app only if the app has Always authorization and if it was running the significant change, visits, or region monitoring location service at the time of its termination.

Your app will be relaunched if you are using region monitoring and you have asked for and received "Always" location permission.  If you only have the provisional always permission - ie you have asked for "Always" but the user has not yet granted it, then your app will not be relaunched.
Also note that this relaunch will only occur if your app was terminated by iOS due to memory pressure. If it was terminated by the user swiping it away it won't be relaunched.

"If it was terminated by the user swiping it away it won't be relaunched." - I just checked this on real device in real environment. This is not true. I killed the application and still get event about exit/ entry. Moreover I killed the app, turned off phone, left the region, turned on phone (I didn't turn on app) and again I get event about leaving the region.

Below your quote there is another info: "Add the background mode capability -
The background modes capability lets the system know whether your app uses background updates (...)" and there is NO info if this is needed also when having only region monitoring or not so this is what I mean infos are very confusing. Additionally a lot of people were claming on forums that monitoring didn't work in background and it worked better/ started to work only when they Enabled Location Updated

Today I also noticed another case, if you turn on When In Use (no Always option yet) and  kill the app and turn off the screen then notification will not come (very not cool for user if there is still no Always option by default). When I unlocked the phone then I got popup about to change permissions to "Always". In this case I've changed permissions into Always but notification about leaving region never came (even if I was outside for long time). Ofc when I entered region it didnt notify me too.

I wonder when I should check it manually if user changed the region or if event will finally come because as I described before when I turned off the phone and changed the region then event was fired. Probably in this case I will just force the second popup about Always permissions...
